# Stop Django from creating migrations if the list of choices of a field changes

Tags: python, django, database-migration

I have a django core app called "foocore".

There are several optional pluging-like apps. For example "superfoo".

In my case every plugin adds a new choice in a model CharField which belongs to "foocore".

Django migrations detect changes if the list of choices get changed.

I think this is not necessary. At least one other developer thinks the same:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22837

```
class ActivePlugin(models.Model):
    plugin_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=get_active_plugins())
```

The code to get the choices:

```
class get_active_plugins(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        for item in ....:
            yield item
```

The core "foocore" gets used in several projects and every installation has a different set of plugins. Django tries to create useless migrations ....

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Yeah this is a terrible feature. I feel your pain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See this bug report and discussion for more info: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22837

The proposed solution was to use a callable as the argument for choices, but it appears this has not been executed for fields but for forms only.

If you really need dynamic choices than a `ForeignKey` is the best solution.

An alternative solution can be to add the requirement through a custom clean method for the field and/or creating a custom form. Form fields do support callable `choices`.

See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33514551/54017

Comment: In that case you might be out of luck for a clean solution. I can only think of hacks to solve it for your case... modifying the choices on runtime, hardcoding the choices if `sys.argv` contains `makemigrations`, etc.

Comment: I cannot get this to work on models choices, according to docs it is only available on forms.ChoiceFields. Trying to add a callable to model choices raises a `(fields.E004) 'choices' must be an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple).`

Comment: This doesn't work for models, only forms. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514058/django-creates-pointless-migrations-on-choices-list-change).

Comment: @Andrew: you are completely right, I misread the original bugreport and the proposed solution.

Comment: It might be worth updating this ticket given that callable support for choices is now merged and available from Django 5.0.2
https://github.com/django/django/commit/691f70c47755c7f55fa75ce607d028f81468b745

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. My choices were dynamic (all years from a starting point to the present) and every year the first time `makemigrations` was run it generated new migrations for the new choice. The solution I found was customizing the field so the `choices` change wouldn't be detected by `makemigrations`:

```
from django.db import models


class YearField(models.IntegerField):

    description = "A year from 2015 to the present"

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super(YearField, self).deconstruct()
        # Ignore choice changes when generating migrations
        kwargs.pop('choices', None)
        return (name, path, args, kwargs)
```

Comment: This solution is good and underrated. I created myself a char field which does not migrate choices and default. I can just use it like any other char field and do not have to create an own form or meta class

Comment: Great solution. I only added "if 'makemigrations' in sys.argv:" just to make sure that choices will be gone only while making migrations.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with a custom field that I made for a Django 1.6 project that had the same general structure. I came to the following solution which works alright:

```
class ActivePluginMeta(ModelBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        # Override choices attr
        cls = models.base.ModelBase.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        setattr(cls._meta.get_field('plugin_name'), 'choices', cls.plugin_name_choices)
        return cls

class ActivePlugin(models.Model, metaclass=ActivePluginMeta):
    plugin_name_choices = get_active_plugins()
    plugin_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=[])
```

That is for python 3, for python 2 you have to specify the metaclass as follows:

```
class ActivePlugin(models.Model):
    __metaclass__ = ActivePluginMeta

    plugin_name_choices = get_active_plugins()
    plugin_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=[])
```

Comment: +1 for being clever but, sadly even this doesn't work anymore (Django 1.10 anyway). I appears that Django now instantiates the model before making the migrations. =(