# Django creates pointless migrations on choices list change

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a model with a choices field using a callable, so that Django doesn't create migrations when a choices list changes, as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788450/stop-django-from-creating-migrations-if-the-list-of-choices-of-a-field-changes) question here.

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    severity = models.IntegerField(choices=get_severity_choices)
    ...

class get_severity_choices(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        for item in SEVERITY_CHOICES:
            yield item
```

where

```
SEVERITY_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Low'),
    (2, 'Medium'),
    (3, 'High'),
)
```

However, I'm getting an error message:

```
quoting.Quote.severity: (fields.E004) 'choices' must be an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple).
```

Comment: for the argument choices only acceptable field is Tuple or it can be list sometimes but over here you are trying to pass a class and look back to the reference, try changin the name of SEVERITY_CHOICES to get_severity_choices.

Comment: I think you can replace `for item in SEVERITY_CHOICES: yield item` with `return iter(SEVERITY_CHOICES)`. Or even `severity = models.IntegerField(choices=SEVERITY_CHOICES)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're mixing up the `choices` argument on a `Model` field, and that on a `forms.ChoiceField` field. In a [model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices), `choices` must be an interable - you cannot pass a callable:

> `choices`: An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) consisting itself of iterables of
>   exactly two items (e.g. [(A, B), (A, B) ...]) to use as choices for
>   this field.

Your `get_severity_choices` class isn't being recognised as an iterable because Django expects it to subclass [`collections.Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Iterable) rather than just expose an `__iter__` method.

You *can* pass [a callable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices) to a `FormField`:

> `choices`: Either an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) of 2-tuples to use as choices for this field, or a callable that returns such an iterable.

For a `Model` field however you must specify your choices beforehand. Also from the docs:

> Note that `choices` can be any iterable object – not necessarily a list
>   or tuple. This lets you construct choices dynamically. But if you find
>   yourself hacking `choices` to be dynamic, you’re probably better off
>   using a proper database table with a ForeignKey. `choices` is meant for
>   static data that doesn’t change much, if ever.

As regards why Django creates the seemingly useless migrations, there is some discussion about that in [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22837):

> This is by design. There are several reasons, not least of which ... that datamigrations at points in history need to have a full
>   accurate representation of the models, including all their options, not
>   just those which affect the database.