# Django migrations changing choices value

Tags: mysql, django

A field has been added to one of my MySQL table previously:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.9.7 on 2017-09-14 00:49
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('my_app', '0102_previous_migrations'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='my_client',
            name='my_team',
            field=models.CharField(choices=[('Unassigned', 'Unassigned'), ('ACT', 'ACT'), ('Korea', 'Korea'), ('National', 'National')], default='Unassigned', max_length=255, verbose_name='My Team'),
        ),
    ]
```

So users have a choices of the above selection in my UI and will be saved into the table my_client:

- Unassigned
- ACT
- Korea
- National

The changes have been deployed and now a beginner like me would like to change, i.e. remove Korea and add 2 new choices: NSW and SA

How would I go about this? Do I need another migration or I will just need to change those choices in the models?

I use this in my model now like this:

```python
class Client(MyAppModel):
    TEAM_CHOICES = (
        ('Unassigned', 'Unassigned'),
        ('ACT', 'ACT'),
        ('Korea', 'Korea'),
        ('National', 'National'),
)

DEFAULT_TEAM = 'Unassigned'
my_team = models.CharField(verbose_name='MyTeam', null=False, max_length=255, choices=TEAM_CHOICES, default=DEFAULT_TEAM)
```

**Update:**

Base on the comment I have, I will need a migration too, a AlterField?

Do I also have to update all the existing value right now in the table my_client if any of them is having Korea to say Unassigned if I would like to remove Korea as a choice? What command can I use in the migration?

Comment: You will need a migration. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514058/django-creates-pointless-migrations-on-choices-list-change/33514551#33514551

Comment: thanks @solarissmoke, how would the migration look like as the one does not show changing just choices?

Comment: It should just show changing choices. What does yours look like?

Answer (score 4):

Figure this out later, hope it helps others beginner like me.

I have to update the Client model

```python
class Client(MyAppModel):
    TEAM_CHOICES = (
        ('Unassigned', 'Unassigned'),
        ('National', 'National'),
        ('NSW', 'NSW'),
        ('SA', 'SA'),
)
```

Then enter this command:

```python
python manage.py makemigrations
```

A migration will be generated:

```python
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('my_app', '0102_previous_migrations'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='my_client',
            name='my_team',
            field=models.CharField(choices=[('Unassigned', 'Unassigned'), ('ACT', 'ACT'), ('National', 'National'), ('NSW', 'NSW'), ('SA', 'SA')], default='Unassigned', max_length=255, verbose_name='My Team'),
        ),
    ]
```

Next to update all the existing values in the table now, referred [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations), enter this command to create an empty migration file:

python manage.py makemigrations --empty my_app

In the new migration file, put something like:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.9.7 on 2017-10-26 06:36
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations

def set_unassigned(apps, schema_editor):
    Client = apps.get_model('my_app', 'my_client')
    for client in Client.objects.all():
        client.account_team = 'Unassigned'
        client.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('my_app', '0104_client_team_update'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(set_unassigned),
    ]
```

Answer (score 4):

A high-level approach:

Create a migration which only adds the new choice. Write a method to take all models with the old choice, and give them a proper new choice `migration.RunPython`. Create a migration which removes the old choice.

Comment: You can even take the `migrations.AlterField` operation of the second migration, delete the migration file (if it contains only that), put the operation in the first migration file, and put the RunPython function in between. That way you have only one migration file, which contains the whole change process.